# How to think while solving question like this? If $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has roots $A$ and $A^n$, then $(ac^n)^{1/(n+1)}+(a^nc)^{1/(n+1)}+b=0$.

Tags: quadratics

I want to know what should be your thinking while solving this question.

> $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has roots $A$ and $A^n$. Prove that $$(ac^n)^{1/(n+1)} + (a^nc)^{1/(n+1)} +b = 0$$

What are you thinking in your mind about the variables, about the steps?

You see, we don’t know $n$, $a$, $b$, $c$,  neither $A$. But we know a equation and it has to be $0$.

I get these questions in mind:

1. it that we require to know value of $n$ since that can tells us a huge guess to what are values of roots?
2. So , in my way of thinking. I feel we need to know $a$, $c$, and $b$ values.

Please do share yours. I do not want a solution. Just how would you think in these types of questions.

Comment: What's the point of raising to the power 1?

Comment: My first step is to ask myself, have I ever seen an equation like $ax^2+bx+c=0$, and to refresh my memory about its roots.  Lucky for me, I _do_ remember seeing this equation before...

Comment: I have checked the Q. No more typos now.

Comment: @kimchilover K. What else ?

Comment: The immediate line of attack: product of roots is $A^{n+1}=c/a$, so $(a^nc)^{1/n+1}=(a^{n+1}(c/a))^{\frac1n+1}=\dots$

Comment: Then I look at the rest of the problem statement and try to connect the new details with what I already know.

Comment: @user10354138 Why not care about the real value of n

Comment: @kimchilover Ohk.

Comment: A^n can only be equal to A. If let us say n is greater than 1 , Only if A  = 1 is what I think@kimchilover

Comment: @Rider Because pinning it down to a nasty expression isn't going to work very nicely with your exponents.

Comment: Hmm k makes sense. We don’t need the original value of any variable like that.

Comment: To be clear: Are those exponents $\frac{1}{n}+1$, or $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @Blue Second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $ax^2 + bx + c = 0\;$ has roots $A$ and $A^n$. Prove that $$\left(ac^n\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+\left(a^nc\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+b=0$$

Since $\;\dfrac ca=A\cdot A^n=A^{n+1}\;,\;$ we get that

$\displaystyle\left(ac^n\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+\left(a^nc\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+b=$

$=\displaystyle\sqrt[n+1]{ac^n}+\sqrt[n+1]{a^nc}+b=$

$=c\;\sqrt[n+1]{\dfrac ac}+a\;\sqrt[n+1]{\dfrac ca}+b=$

$=c\;\sqrt[n+1]{\dfrac1{A^{n+1}}}+a\;\sqrt[n+1]{A^{n+1}}+b=$

$=\dfrac cA+aA+b=$

$=\dfrac1A\left(c+aA^2+bA\right)=$

$=\dfrac1A\left(aA^2+bA+c\right)=$

$=0\;\;$ indeed $\;A\;$ is a root of $\;ax^2+bx+c\;.$

So we have proved that

$\displaystyle\left(ac^n\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+\left(a^nc\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}+b=0\;.$

Answer (score 1):

(While I often like to use the Viete relations, they aren't strictly necessary here...)

Since we are given the roots of the quadratic equation, we can write
$$ a \ · \ (x - A) \ · (x - A^n) \ \ = \ \ ax^2 + bx + c \ \ . $$

This tells us that $ \ b \ = \ a \ · (-A \ - \ A^n) \ \Rightarrow \ a · (A \ + \ A^n) \ + \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ $  and $ \ a· A · A^n \ = \ a·A^{n+1} \ = \ c \ \ . $

Carry on...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my hand written proof:

[image]

Comment: Common why a down vote when I am right.

Comment: My friend , I totally upvote it. Thanks. I didn’t downvote

Comment: @Rider Thanks man. I appreciate that.

Comment: Please take the effort to put it into [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

One point of it it's getting searchable ... which is advantageous for worthwhile contributions $\ddot\smile$